# Apply Assertion on JDBC Request

Tags: database, jdbc, jmeter, load-testing, assertion

I am new to using JMeter for load testing. I have to fetch records from table in database and apply some assertions to the values returned for specific columns.

I am successfully able to get the response from the database using the query but I am stuck on the assertion part.

Following is the result from DB using JDBC request which is correct:

```
id   username  bonus
101  sam       0.1
102  john      0.2
103  smith     0.3
```

Now I want to assert that username 'john' has bonus as '0.2'

I added a Debug Sampler and observed that the result get stored in this format :

```
res_#=1
res_1=101
res_2=102
res_3=103
```

But I am getting no where with these results. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cannot you just amend your SQL query to look like `SELECT bonus FROM your_table WHERE username = 'john'`?
2. I think your JDBC Request configuration is not very correct, if the query returns 3 columns you need to define 3 [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to hold the results

   [image]

   in this case you will have variables like:

   [image]

   See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more details

If you cannot amend your query and still need to get the "bonus" value for "john" and assert it I think you will have to go for [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and implement comparison logic in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/), example code:

```
1.upto(vars.get('username_#') as int, {
    if (vars.get('username_' + it) == 'john') {
        if (vars.get('bonus_' + it) != '0.2') {
            AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
            AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Bonus mismatch, expected: 0.2, got: ' + vars.get('bonus_' + it))
        }
    }
})
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. This helped a lot 